# Creating a login page with php - Can't see where the error lies

Tags: php, mysql, authentication

EDIT: ASSIGNMENT WORK. Please don't mention External Libraries or complicated procedures that deal with security issues.

I want to implement a very basic login page that compares the users username and password with ones stored in a database (using MySql) and then redirect to another webpage that is only available to logged in users. I have looked at these two tutorials:

http://frozenade.wordpress.com/2007/11/24/how-to-create-login-page-in-php-and-mysql-with-session/

http://www.phpro.org/tutorials/Basic-Login-Authentication-with-PHP-and-MySQL.html

and I've attempted to use both techniques. The second one kept giving me server errors, and the first one gives me the login page, and doesn't return any errors, but then when pressing the submit button, it just doesn't do anything. I've followed it practically word for word, only changing the file names and some database column names to fit with my pre-existing stuff, but to no avail. This login page has given me an almighty headache and I would really like to get this out of the way and done with now.

LOGIN PAGE

```
<?php
// Inialize session
session_start();

// Check, if user is already login, then jump to secured page
if (isset($_SESSION['username'])) {
    header('Location: RecordEvents.php');
}
?>
```

... skip all the unnecessary parts

```
<h1>Login</h1>
<?php
    if(!empty($errorMessage)) 
    {
        echo("<p>There was a problem with your login:</p>\n");
        echo("<ul>" . $errorMessage . "</ul>\n");
    } 
?>
<form action="loginscript.php" method="post">
Username:
<input type="text" name="username" /> </br>
Password:
<input type="password" name="password" /> </br>
<p>
    <!--the submit button with an altered value. once selected the validation script will run-->
    <input type="submit" name="login" value="Allons-y!" />
</p>

</form>
```

CONFIG.INC (I tried at first naming the file .php but that made no difference.)

```
<?php

$hostname = 'localhost';
$dbname   = 'clubresults';
$username = 'newuser';
$password = 'password';

// Let's connect to host
mysql_connect($hostname, $username, $password) or DIE('Connection to host is failed,     perhaps the service is down!');
// Select the database
mysql_select_db($dbname) or DIE('Database name is not available!');

?>
```

LOGINSCRIPT.PHP

```
<?php

// Inialize session
session_start();

// Include database connection settings
include('Inlcude\config.inc');

// Retrieve username and password from database according to user's input
$login = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM admin_passwords WHERE (Username = '" .     mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['username']) . "') and (Password = '" .     mysql_real_escape_string(md5($_POST['password'])) . "')");

// Check username and password match
if (mysql_num_rows($login) == 1) {
// Set username session variable
$_SESSION['username'] = $_POST['username'];
// Jump to secured page
header('Location: RecordEvents.php');
}
else {
// Jump to login page
header('Location: Login.php');
}

?>
```

RECORDEVENTS.PHP

```
<?php  
// Inialize session
session_start();

// Check, if username session is NOT set then this page will jump to login page
if (!isset($_SESSION['username'])) {
    header('Location: Login.php');
}
Include ('Include\eventscript.php'); 
?>
```

... blah blah

```
<?php
    if(!empty($errorMessage)) 
    {
        echo("<p>There was an error with your form:</p>\n");
        echo("<ul>" . $errorMessage . "</ul>\n");
    } 
?>
<form action="RecordEvents.php" method="post">
Name: <input type="text" name="EventName" value="<?php print $varEventname;?>" />   </br>
Date: <input type="text" name="EventDate" placeholder="yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss" value="<?php print $varEventdate;?>" /> </br>
Location: <input type="text" name="Location" value="<?php print $varLocation;?>" /> </br>
<p>
    <!--the submit button with an altered value. once selected the validation script will run-->
    <input type="submit" name="formSubmit" value="Allons-y!" />
    <!--the reset button to empty the form and start again-->
    <input type="reset" name="formReset" value="Try Again" />
</p>
</form>
```

the db is called clubresults, the table i'm using is admin_passwords and the column names are: Username, Password.

Can anyone spot the error I am obviously making?

Comment: I didn't read the whole thing, but I recommend to use some framework or library - that come as it is - for that kind of issues. That's because IT security isn't trivial. So, let's take a look to symfony2 or its security library

Comment: I just want to get this done without using external libraries. It can't be that difficult to get it done without it? I just need it to work, i'm not particularly interested in any other security related issues other than: if they don't have the username/password, they can't visit that page.

Comment: "if they don't have the username/password, they can't visit that page" you're totally wrong!

Comment: I mean that there are a lot of security attack that are well-known and could be used against your code (where "your code" is a generic one). If you require a login for a page, you want to control EVERY TIME if the user was logged in. For do that, you - maybe - want to store a cookie. But cookies could be steal or falsified and so on.. And that is only an example ... So, if you want to write it from scratch ok, but keep in mind ALL OF THOSE things

Comment: I don't care about that sort of stuff! this page is never going to be live in anyway shape or form, and as soon as I'm done with it I am scrapping all knowledge of this subject and never ever going into web development ever again. All I need is for the damn page to function.

Comment: Ok, but keep calm. I've only awared you about it and give a precious advice

Comment: Not to mention the security hole sending passwords as plaintext over the internet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your spelling.

```
include('Inlcude\config.inc');
```

Please see this.

```
$login = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM admin_passwords WHERE username = '" .mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['username']) . "' and password = '" .mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['password']) . "'");
```

I removed the md5() function.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.md5.php

This is what really happens when there is an md5 in your query.
Lets say that you input the ff.

username = username
password = password

Your query will be like this, with md5() in your $_POST['password'].

```
SELECT * FROM admin_passwords WHERE username = 'username' and password = '5f4dcc3b5aa765d61d8327deb882cf99'
```

Please see the link above for more info!

Comment: AHH! THANK YOU. I didn't even see that stupid md5() function or that I had spelled include wrong. It's working now. Wow, I feel intelligent...

Answer (score 0):

First thing I see is

```
include('Inlcude\config.inc');
```

Obviously, the path is wrong. Further, sanitize your code. E.g. `include` doesn't require parentheses and should be written in lower case always, like

```
include 'Include\config.inc';
```

Next, are you sure, there is only one entry in your database? As it is defined to only load the recordevents script on

```
mysql_num_rows($login) == 1
```

Sometimes while developing, you may have two equal rows.

Comment: I am pretty darn sure that there is only one entry in that table. I have mysql running along side so I can confirm that all the data entry I have to do actually works. As for the include not needing parentheses, I realize that, but having them in there doesn't affect the code. Either way, I changed all the offending includes and it's still not redirecting me to the desired page.

Comment: and what do you mean by sanitize?

Comment: How did you debug so far? Have you tried to echo some custom string instead of redirecting? So, if `mysql_num_rows($login) == 1` do an `echo "SUCCESS";` and else an `echo "FAILURE";`. That's the most simple debugging everyone can do. What is the result?

Comment: Sanitize as in making your script secure, just as @DonCallisto already stated. But since this script is never going to be online, it probably doesn't matter. Unless this is some kind of IT homework and your teacher is picky.

Comment: it returned a fail. So it's not correctly checking the database?

Comment: I guess sephoy's pointing to the md5() function resolved your issue?